# DB2 connection without specifying username and password (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, db2

I have installed DB2, and on the same server I'm trying to establish a connection in PowerShell.  It seems, however, that I have to provide the username and password in the connection string in plain text.  As I am trying to create a scheduled task on a secure system, this is not an ideal situation.

I have checked the old standby, http://connectionstrings.com, but I cannot find any string that does not explicitly include the username and password.  Is there such a string?  Maybe use a different provider?  Below is the code I'm using.

```
$cn=new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=TLMA;HostName=xxx;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;CurrentSchema=DB2")
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Exception calling "Fill" with "1" arguments(s): " SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "3" ("PASSWORD MISSING").  SQLSTATE=08001"

I'm open to any idea on how to solve this.

**UPDATE:**  I've discovered that the instance has an Authentication setting.  It's currently set to SERVER.

A connection string that looks like this:

```
$cn=new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=TLMA;HostName=xxx;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;Authentication=KERBEROS;CurrentSchema=DB2")
```

might work (I'm not sure), but it seems that it would require me to change the Authentication setting to KERBEROS.  I don't know if this will break the application that's currently using the uid/pwd model.

Answer (score 0):

I can call db2 commands from PowerShell when I load the profile, and the connection takes as credentials the already authenticated user:

```
set-item -path env:DB2CLP -value "**$$**"
db2 connect to mydb
```

However, I do not know how you can then use the connections as a resource.

Take a look at this working example: https://github.com/angoca/log4db2/blob/master/src/main/scripts/install.ps1

Also, try to change the security mechanism in DB2, in order to trust clients.

Comment: Once I figured it out, it does work, but to take the eventual output from this method and put it back into a DataSet object is a massive pain.  Sorry, but I can't consider this a valid answer.  But I learned quite a bit about using DB2, thanks!

Comment: I know what you mean, because my solution is for shell, not for working with objects as you want.